# Авторизация пользователя в .htaccess и nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

К папке ограничен доступ через `.htaccess`, однако для статических файлов типа `*.zip` это не работает, потому что их обрабатывает `nginx` и на `.htaccess` не обращает внимания. Как ограничить доступ не передавая `*.zip` файлы апачу... похоже что ngnix собран без ngx_http_auth_basic_module!

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в конфиге ngnix те же настроки, что в .htaccess, естественно сохраняя синтаксис. 
Вот конвертер из .htaccess в ngnix rule:

[.htaccess в ngnix rule](http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/)

```
location РЕГУЛЯКА_ДЛЯ_К_ФАЙЛАМ {
    auth_basic "Admin Zone";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/example.com/admin/.htpasswd;
}
```

.htpasswd указываете тот же, что и в .htaccess

Comment: не фурычит конвертор!
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/local/nginx/html/anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/rew.php on line 520

Comment: Я не проверял))
В любом случае почитайте про ngnix rule и напишите те же условия для nginx...

Comment: вот поправил, так должно работать...

Comment: это было прописано, проблема в том, что ngnix собран без ngx_http_auth_basic_module!

Comment: пересобрать nginx пока не хватает мозгов, ошибки лезут...